# Code Sign Error - Profile not available in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build/sign an update for an application that I haven't built on this Mac before. I am logged into the same developer account and have published other apps on this machine.

When I try to do the verification before uploading to the store I get the following error:

> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No
>   provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate
>   and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier
>   “com.appname.mobile” were found.

I tried the obvious solution of Preferences -> Accounts -> Details -> Download All but the strange part there is that the profile **does not show up** yet I can see it while logged into the Apple Developer site. It's right there **com.appname.mobile** and it expires 9/29/2017 so the fact that it does not show up in XCode is really strange to me.

I hope I am just missing a step for building an existing app on a new machine because I have never any issues with this process before. Any insight would be most appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked in "Keychain Access" that you have the distribution certificate/key that matches this specific profile?

Comment: I see the correct "iPhone Distribution: <company name>" cert/key in keychain.

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg This answer may help you, it's fresh.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39371910/661022

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your old mac machine & export the necessary `keychains certificates`. Once `certificates` exported.

Now you can install your `certificates` on new mac by double clicking on `certificated` files. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I see the correct "iPhone Distribution: <company name>" cert/key in keychain and when I view the account in XCode I see all of the provisioning profiles EXCEPT the one I am looking for.

Comment: Try to remove it & install again. Restart your Xcode as well.

Comment: Same result, I can see other provisioning profiles but not the one I am after.  Logged into developer.apple.com I can see them all.

Comment: Then may be you need to generate new certificate from your new mac.